# Downloading generated excel file using ajax

Tags: java, ajax, excel, struts2, download

I am developing an application using struts2 framework. When user provides date range, I need to prepare the reports excel file and show that in download pop-up. I am able to create io stream of excel, but I am not getting how can I open that pop-up using ajax.

I am generating file on the fly and returns the stream. Therefore not able to give file path. I want ajax call to show some message like `"Please wait.."`. Because file generation takes more time and it looks like link is not working..

Comment: Can you post the AJAX call and some of the action code here?

Comment: do you got any way to do this?

Comment: I have given normal form submit (normal call to server) in form I have used `target="_blank" ` attribute due to this it will opening in new window and therefore there is no chance to feel like freeze the current window (since for file creation it takes more time and it was liked as a frozen link)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing Ajax about downloading a file.

Your request can be an ajax request, but simply give the generated file path and the browser will do the downloading.

Comment: I am generating file on the fly and returns the stream. Therefore not able to give file path. I want ajax call to show some message like "Please wait..". Because file generation takes more time and it looks like link is not working..

Comment: When the response is a file, it will be automatically done.. Just show the waiting message after you make the ajax request... Struts docs have details about file download.

Comment: If I create file and save on server, It will allocate the space on server which is not necessary because the file is once download it will not used again

Answer (score 1):

No need to perform any `AJAX` calls.

You just need to return the `byte[]` as a [Struts2 `Stream` result](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/stream-result.html), 
configured with a `ContentDisposition: attachment;` (and not `ContentDisposition: inline`, that will try to open it inside the browser instead of asking about downloading or opening with a desktop application).

To notify the user that *something is going on*, that the request is sent and the system is not frozen, you need an `Loading OVERLAY`.

An Overlay is an element that is placed over your page, generally with a partially transparent background, an animated image saying "Loading..." , and a *modal* behavior (it won't close until the page is changed, and it will prevent double post of the same request, like double clicks etc...).

Of course if you open an attachment, the page will not change, then you'll need to intercept the end of the downloading and close the overlay by yourself, or give the user a button to close it.

To intercept it, you can try the [`Struts2 Execute and Wait Interceptor`](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-execandwait-interceptor-example/).

If you want to create a custom overlay, you can generate your Loading images with the [`ajaxload.info Generator`](http://www.ajaxload.info/).

If you instead don't want to reinvent the wheel, you can take a look at existing overlays, like those from [`jQuery TOOLS`](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/overlay/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

On the success method of ajax do not return the stream, instead save the file on server and open a pop up with address to an action that returns correct file. But pop ups might be blocked in some browsers so you need to allow that for your site (local host or other URL)

Comment: I don't want to save file on server. It will allocate the space on server which is not necessary because the file is once download it will not used again